# How do you identify reducing / non-reducing sugar by looking at structure?

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry, carbonyl-compounds, carbohydrates

Identifying reducing / non-reducing sugar been confusing me for a while now , I know that reducing sugar contain aldehyde or ketone group . It's easy to identify them in monosaccharides but this becomes confusing in case of disaccharides! 
[image]

I fail to see carbonyl group here, How can I identify reducing / non-reducing sugar by looking at structure in picture? can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Many sugars are drawn in the cyclic, closed form where the carbonyl group has been converted to a [hemiacetal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemiacetal).

[image]

Once you realize that a hemiacetal can equilibrate with a carbonyl (*e.g*. it is a carbonyl in disguise), identification of reducing sugars becomes easier.

Here is an example from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reducing_sugar), it is Maltose, the same as your third compound

[image]

See the aldehyde in the open isomer drawn on the right; see how it can close to form a hemiacetal on the left.

Comment: The way I always heard what that (in a sugar) was that the _anomeric_ C atom was the one bound to two oxygens.  And if one of those two oxygens was part of an OH group, then the sugar was a reducing sugar.